This site can't be reached when a service expose on kubernetes
I'm new to kubernetes and i'm trying to write file.yaml to expose a the-hive service on my kubernetes cluster. The file is as follows:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: thehive-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: thehive
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: thehive
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: thehive
        image: strangebee/thehive:5.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: thehive-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: thehive
  ports:
   - name: http
     protocol: TCP
     port: 80
     targetPort: 80


The pod, deployment, and service run successfully. But when I go to do it minikube service thehive-service and gives me an address, the browser says: "This site can't be reached". I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Does the same image work in plain Docker, without Kubernetes?  Is the service inside the container listening on 0.0.0.0:80, or somewhere else?

Yes, the image should also work on docker. I'm a bit confused about the listening ports.

If you for example docker run -p 12345:80 strangebee/thehive:5.2, can you reach the container on http://localhost:12345/?  If not, that suggests there's something wrong with the image or its configuration, and not necessarily the Kubernetes manifests.

I tried to run it and I actually can't see the container.

@Mario can't see the container means it's not running or any other issue..? can you check the logs and let us know the issue. I have also included some basic troubleshooting steps below, let me know if you need commands for those

It all depends on where and how you have configured your kubernetes cluster, let me add further to what Mr. David Maze has suggested. Assuming that you have configured your kubernetes cluster as mentioned in  the below cases:
Case 1: If you are using docker desktop as your container runtime for minikube and deployed it on your local system as David Maze suggested you can expose the application using docker commands and try accessing it by using that system's browser.
Even after exposing if you are still not able to access your application check if the application is running properly, you can verify this by going through the docker logs.
Check whether there are any apparmor, UFW or SElinux rules enabled or causing issues from your application port to reach outside.
Case 2: If you have deployed your application inside a VM, which you have provisioned on any cloud provider and are trying to access the application from your local system. It won’t be possible to access the application using localhost, you need to get the public IP address of the VM on which you have deployed your application and configure necessary firewall rules for exposing that application outside.
Note: If you are using any playground for practicing kubernetes, your application cannot be exposed outside that playground.

Since you are saying that your container is not running, there might be a possibility that your application is facing some issues. This can be found out from container logs or you can try running your application on the local system, if it works well and if you are able to access it using the browser try replicating the same in docker

You should also check whether you have packaged all your application dependencies along side the application code while containerizing your application.
